# How to handle mutiple URL in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Say I am using baseurl of http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/ to login. So after login test (successful login) the base url is changed to http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryreservation.php?osCsid=929093474fd911e10f3a61562f069efd with a token. So this page test will be a different test but it should come from previous login. Creating two different test cases and running them as a suite is failing as the token is different each time. How to handle this??

Answer (score 0):

SwitchTo().window()
*in tabs index starts with 0*